# Knowing if a Streetview is available for a specific latitude/longitude before launching it

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

I'm trying to find a way to know if Streetview is available for a specific latitude and longitude before showing it to the user. This is my current code that correctly shows a Streetview if it's available or shows a black screen. I want to basically remove the black screen situation.

https://gist.github.com/speakerbug/33f267fd3a90dbd3ca07eae5b6c7c8f5

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it in Maps SDK for iOS, but you can check existence of panorama using [Street View Image Metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) web service.

For example, the following web service request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?location=41.391073%2C2.180614&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

will return

```
{
    "copyright":"© Rodrigo Bastias",
    "date":"2017-03",
    "location":{
        "lat":41.3910524,
        "lng":2.1806449
    }, "pano_id":"CAoSK0FGMVFpcE5OVHRRTERHX1lzRF93XzRZb2YyajJwaXFXUkFRQzg5THJuOTg.",
    "status":"OK"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This probably isn't the best solution, but it does work for my use case.